# Is it okay to increase the gain of the master stereo output if enough headroom is available?

Tags: stereo, cubase, quality, sound-quality

Will I suffer any quality loss if in my sequencer (Cubase 10) I turn up the master stereo out volume to reach a certain minimum volume, if this works out without clipping (enough headroom present on the total mix) ?

Comment: X/Y problems....why do you need to do this?

Comment: XY? Because i don't want to re-mix all my tracks in relation to each other as the current balance is just perfect, simply too low on volume.

Comment: why is the volume too low?

Comment: Because all the channels are set at a fairly low volume or the instruments that drive them are.

Comment: i see. are there any recorded audio tracks in your mix, (anything with an analog noise floor)  or is it all virtual instruments? (eg; entirely in the box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's shouldn't be any quality loss if you're not clipping. The noise floor, if any, would be louder but the Signal-to-Noise Ratio would stay the same because you're applying a constant gain. You may want to check the "Normalize" function in Cubase (and nearly every DAWs) which automates this process.